# Proper way to call UIView#setNeedsDisplay for @property change

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Consider that we have own a custom view that extends UIView.

It may have multiple properties that affects it's appearance.
So, Whenever any of theses properties is changed, We have to call `setNeedsDisplay`.

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor* someColor;
@end

@implemetation MyView
-(void)setSomeColor:(UIColor*) someColor
{
    if(_someColor == someColor) return;
    [self willChangeValueForKey: @"someColor"];
    _someColor = someColor;

    // we needs to call this to re-render.
    [self setNeedsDisplay]; 

    [self didChangeValueForKey: @"someColor"];
}
@end
```

In above code, there is only one property. 
However, What if we have a lots of properties that affects appearance, It can be very painful task. We have to write very similar codes multiple times, and auto synthesizing feature of objective-c seems to be useless for this case.

Is there anyway to make it clean and simple?

For example, some kind of synthesize directive macro or annotation likes:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic, needsDisplay) UIColor* someColor;
@end
```

or

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NeedsDisplay UIColor* someColor;
@end
```

Comment: Do you need to call setNeedsDisplay? Have you tested that? You certainly don't need to do that if you change a view's background color, for instance.

Comment: @rdelmar because `UIView#setBackgroundColor` implementation of Apple contains `setNeedsDisplay` also. All appearance properties from Apple have same mechanism. I mean that custom properties that affects appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use key value observing, register your self an observer and send `setNeedsDisplay` message properly.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"someColor"] || /*other property*/) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay] ;
    }
    /*
     Be sure to call the superclass's implementation *if it implements it*.
     NSObject does not implement the method.
     */
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                         ofObject:object
                           change:change
                           context:context];
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't you have to register for each keyPath separately? That would make the code just as long as the OP's way.

Comment: @rdelmar It is true that I have to register each keyPath separately but I needn't override `setProperty` method, KVO happen automatic. KVO helps handle the logic(`setNeedsDisplay`) in one place which I think is better from the perspective of design pattern.